# How do I trigger an event after a script is done running in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using select-chain plugin and have the following code in order to populate a second select box based on another select box:

```
$('#rating_state').selectChain({ target: $("#rating_county"), url: 'scripts/chain.php', data: { ajax: true }, selected: '<?php echo $actual_rating_county?>'}).trigger("change");
```

My problem is when the page initially loads, it triggers my select2 plugin before the script is done running and the select box actually appears blank as a result.  If I set it up so that the following performs on click it fixes the issue when clicked:

```
$('#rating_county').select2();
```

The entire javascript is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#rating_state').selectChain({ target: $("#rating_county"), url: 'scripts/chain.php', data: { ajax: true }, selected: '<?php echo $actual_rating_county?>'}).trigger("change");

$('.select2').select2({
    placeholder: "Select an option",
    allowClear: true
});
$('#rating_state').change(function(){
    $('#rating_county').select2();
});
});
```

Comment: put your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here });`

Comment: I'm assuming that scripts/chain.php is your script.  Do you want that script to load onto your page right away, or are you clicking a button to load that script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your entire code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() { //code here });
```

as Khawer said above.

Comment: Sorry, should have already mentioned that it is in $(document).ready(function(){}.

Comment: Updated. Sorry about that.

Comment: Normally I would just tell you to run `.select2()` as a callback when `.selectChain()` is completed, but I checked for documentation about `.selectChain()` and it appears that its an older (possibly deprecated or unsupported) jQuery plugin. I’m unsure if it even has a callback ability.